# box aligned based on top border, but with dynamic width

Tags: vertical-alignment

I want to have a box, aligned based on top border. I can do this with `minipage[t]`, but i would have to specify the width, which i do not want. 
What is thus the simplest way to have a top-aligned box, with dynamic width?

Comment: The [`varwidth` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) provides `varwidth` which is *exactly* like `minipage`, but shrinks to the natural width of it's contents. Is this what you're after? If not, please provide more detail - perhaps in the form of an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a short example showing the difference between `varwidth` (from the [`varwidth` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth)) and other fixed-width boxes like `\parbox` and `minipage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth
\begin{document}
Some text \fbox{\parbox[t]{0.25\textwidth}{in here \rule{5em}{1pt} \par and here}}\ 
Some text \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}in here \rule{5em}{1pt} \par and here\end{minipage}}    Some text \fbox{\begin{varwidth}[t]{0.25\textwidth}in here \rule{5em}{1pt} \par and here\end{varwidth}}
\end{document}
```

Note how the width for each box is specified as `0.25\textwidth`. However, only the last shrunk down to the natural width of the contents.

Shrinking is a natural process in terms of boxing. Enlarging in a similar context as above is less natural, since one would not know where to start breaking lines.

Comment: @nicolasroy: Yes, you need to know what to search for in order to find things - slightly catch-22-ish. `:)`